# ansible-playbook: "Failed to update cache: unknown reason"

Tags: ansible, apt-get, package-management

I am trying to deploy `kypo` cyber range and am following [its official guide](https://docs.crp.kypo.muni.cz/installation-guide/kypo-crp-deployment/#deploy). While deploying the whole range using `ansible-playbook`, I am stuck on above error:

```
TASK [docker : install prerequisites] ******************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.211.208]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: unknown reason"}
```

I have manually checked `apt-get update` which initially gave me a notification of:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x) to add `[amd=64] to repository` which cleaned the error. Now `apt-get update` runs with without any warnings or errors, but ansible-playbook keeps on generating this error.

I changed the verbosity level and got:

```
fatal: [192.168.211.208]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
       "module_args": {
            "allow_unauthenticated": false,
            "autoclean": false,
            "autoremove": false,
            "cache_valid_time": 0,
            "deb": null,
            "default_release": null,
            "dpkg_options": "force-confdef,force-confold",
            "force": false,
            "force_apt_get": false,
            "install_recommends": null,
            "name": [
                "apt-transport-https",
                "ca-certificates"
            ],
            "only_upgrade": false,
            "package": [
                "apt-transport-https",
                "ca-certificates"
            ],
            "policy_rc_d": null,
            "purge": false,
            "state": "present",
            "update_cache": true,
            "update_cache_retries": 5,
            "update_cache_retry_max_delay": 12,
            "upgrade": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to update apt cache: unknown reason"
 }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kypo CRP, while playing the ansible playbook the error was actually coming from one of the instances of openstack which I found out by increasing verbosity in command `-vvvv`. Everything was fine with the host machine. So I look for changes in instances and the root cause was there was no internet access. Once I managed to connect them to external world, the error went away.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone getting this as a first hit in the future, if you are certain there are no connection or internet issues: there is another solution to this. If your apt task includes `update_cache: true`, ensure that there are no warnings or errors when running `apt update` on the remote machine.
In my case, there was a missing signature for a kubernetes list, which was a list not used anymore.
The warning I got after running `sudo apt update` was:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
```

Removing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list` resulted in no errors or warnings from running `apt update`, and fixed the ansible issues.
The task then completed without issues and I was able to install packages using the apt task, including `update_cache: true`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by resolving warning messages on target host after `apt-get update` execution. Any warnings are critical for this ansible task.
Example:

```
Err:7 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
Fetched 409 kB in 1s (407 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
W: Failed to fetch https://apt.kubernetes.io/dists/kubernetes-xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your firewall isn't blocking ports required by apt. I hadn't opened port 80 or 443 which was causing apt to fail.

I found this by running `sudo apt update` manually on the remote server which gave me a list of "Cannot initiate the connection to..." type warning messages which included the URL + PORT of the endpoint apt was trying to reach.

See [manpages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/sources.list.5.html) for a list of ports that you might need to open.

I suspect that udp-53 also needs to be open for DNS discovery. This is untested since I already had 53 open.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem occurred because I did not allow access to port 80 in the pFsense firewall rule used in my study laboratory: by default, Pfsense does not create access rules for additional interfaces, as in my case.

Executing the command from the server I verified the connection being blocked.

Releasing port 80 communicated with Ansible and installed the packages using "apt".

Kind regards.